# Управление интернет соединением с помощью C#

Tags: c#, сеть

Есть необходимость замедлить или полностью отключить отдачу данных определенного процесса, либо всей сети в целом. Есть мысль об использовании реестра, но пока ничего не нашел.

Вкратце, будет программа, которая по клику будет останавливать передачу данных и возвращать обратно. Если есть мысли, подскажите.

Comment: Инжектитесь в процесс, перехватываете `send/recv` из `ws2_32.dll`, и дальше делаете с передаваемыми/принимаемыми данными что хотите. Правда это не на C# придется делать

Comment: А На каком языке мне это реализовать ?

Comment: Проще всего на C++

Comment: @Zergatul: Ну перехватили вы, и что делать дальше с отправляемыми данными — дропнуть?

Comment: @VladD для блокирующего сокета можно вставить банальный sleep, для неблокирующего - записывать передаваемые данные в буфер, а потом с буфера отправлять в оригинальный send. Не совсем понятно, что хочет автор, разрыва соединения, или просто притормозить трафик на небольшое время.

Comment: @Zergatul: Хм. Ну допустим. А антивирус на такое действие не посмотрит косо?

Comment: @VladD не думаю. Сейчас многие программы​ добавляют свои dll-ки в AppInit_dlls (стандартный софт на ноутбуках, или что-то с драйверами Nvidia). А для чего ещё нужно добавлять длл-ку в чужие процессы кроме как перехвата winapi.

Comment: Ну, одно дело перехватывать установку нестандартного разрешения экрана, а другое дело — общение с интернетом.